# Java.NullPointerException null

Tags: java, null, nullpointerexception

Here are snippets from my code:

```
class Lines{
int nameMax() throws IOException{
    // initialize variables
    // These will be the largest number of characters in name
    int namelen = 0;

    //These will be the current word lenght.     
    int namelenx = 0;

    ... 

    while(name != null){
        name = br.readLine();
        namelenx = name.length();

    ...

        if(namelenx > namelen) namelen = namelenx;


    }

    float nameleny = namelen/2; //Divides by 2 to find midpoint

    namelen = Math.round(nameleny); //Value is rounded

    return namelen;
}   
}
```

I am using BlueJ, and whenever I try to run this it is giving me the error in the title and highlighting `namelenx = name.length();` There are String variables for `name` as it was part of the code I cut out. Helping answers please. Thanks.

Comment: Currently we can't see any string variable `name`. Where is it defined?

Comment: You'll need to at least all references to the name variable to your code example for us to be able to help.

Comment: Like I said, I cut out that code from my snippet, `name` is String. No worries, someone helped

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It throws **NPE** when `br.readLine()` returns `null`, as you invoke `length()` on null.
your while loop should be something like below:

```
while((name= br.readLine())!=null){
        namelenx = name.length();
```

Now, even if `bufferedReader` returns null on `readLine()` your while would terminate.

Answer (score 1):

Probably, you want to change

```
while(name != null)
```

to

```
while((name = br.readline()) != null)
```

This way you are checking the la read from `br` against `null` and you can be sure `name` is never `null`.

Answer (score 0):

```
name = br.readLine();
```

is likely returning null. Is that what you'd expect ? From [the doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#readLine%28%29), it returns:

> A String containing the contents of the line, not including any
>   line-termination characters, or null if the end of the stream has been
>   reached

so you've likely reached the end of your input.

Answer (score 0):

The proper way to do this is:

```
String name = null;

while((name = br.readLine()) != null) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: The initialization of 'name' to null is redundant and therefore not proper.